# How is the compile time check of the type of annotations changed in Java 5?

Tags: java, generics, java-5

I am looking at the changes introduced in Java 5 , the following piece of documentation looks unclear to me .

> ```
> <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationType);
> ```
>
> This is a generic method. It infers the value of its type parameter T from its argument, and returns an appropriate instance of
>   T, as illustrated by the following snippet:
>
> ```
>     Author a = Othello.class.getAnnotation(Author.class);
> ```
>
> Prior to generics, you would have had to cast the result to `Author`. Also you would have had no way to make the compiler check that
>   the actual parameter represented a subclass of `Annotation`.

I would still have been able to make the compiler check that the parameter represented a subclass of `Annotation` by using `Annotation` as the parameter type . What am I missing here, how is the compile time check changed with the introduction of generics?

I agree that I will not need to cast the result now though.

Comment: [Annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) were added in Java 5 as well. Annotations, generics and lambdas are the biggest changes I can think of since Java 1.4 - there's also everything in `java.time` and `try-with-resources` and `java.util.concurrent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"...represented a subclass..."* does not mean instance of a subclass. In that case you *could* use `Annotation` as a parameter type. It instead means an instance of `Class` that corresponds to a subclass of `Annotation`.

Without generics:

```
Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationType);
```

You could pass any `Class` to the method. For instance:

```
SomeType.class.getAnnotation(Object.class);
```

While `Object` is not actually a subtype of `Annotation`.

But with generics, you have a type bound, and the `Class` itself has a generic parameter that is the type it encodes.

With generics, passing `Object.class`, which has the type of `Class<Object>`, would throw a compiler error, since `T` would be `Object`, and `Object` does not conform to the bound: `<T extends Annotation>`.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing here, how is the compile time check changed with the introduction of generics?

First thing.  Annotations were introduced in Java 5 too.

But lets assume that they existed before then.  The signature of the (hypothetical) pre-Java 5 version of `getAnnotation` would have to be:

```
 Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationType);
```

so the getting the author annotation would need to be written as:

```
 Author a = (Author) Othello.class.getAnnotation(Author.class);
```

The type signature of `getAnnotation` only allows the compiler to know that an `Annotation` is returned.  In does not know that a specific subtype (`Author`) of `Annotation` is returned.  Therefore the explicit typecast<sup>1</sup> is necessary to perform the runtime check.

Now, you could also hypothesize that they *could have* made a special case for `getAnnotation` (since this is a system class).  However, the example is to illustrate a point about *normal* Java type checking.  And besides, there are other examples in Java 4 and earlier where they could have added similarr special cases, and didn't.  (Thank heavens!)

---

<sup>1 - In fact, if you examine the generate bytecodes for the call sequence in the generic case, you will see that the compiler has inserted an implicit type-cast for the result assignment.  This is necessary, because it is possible for a generic method to use unchecked conversions and return an object that violates the type constraint that connects the argument and result types.</sup>